# SELECT E-mail и UPDATE E-mail в бд в случае если одинаковых E-mail много в бд

Tags: php, select, mysql

Добрый день.
Пишу личный кабинет пользователя.
В личном кабинете можно менять все данные пользователя с помощью формы.
Если пользователь захочет поменять свой E-mail на уже занятый E-mail, то произойдёт ошибка.
Вопрос в том, как проверить при обновлении информации в бд есть ли уже E-mail в базе, если нет, то обновить его на тот, который он указал в поле формы. Но при всём при этом, если у него остаётся старый email, скрипт должен всё равно обновить его, не сказав о том, что E-mail уже есть в базе данных. 
Извиняюсь за длинное и не очень понятное объяснение =)
Помогите !

Пример как я делаю, но ничего не выходит:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_user = '$email_user'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 1){
    $data["error"] = array(
        "Ошибка" => "Данный E-mail уже используется"
    );
}
```

ну и дальше udate идёт...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первый запрос добавьте услови:

```
$email_user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_user']);
$user_id = (int)$_POST['user_id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `email_user` = '$email_user' AND `user_id` != '$user_id'";
$res = mysql_query($query);

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 1){
    $data["error"] = array(
        "Ошибка" => "Данный E-mail уже используется"
    );
} else {
    // апдейтим запись юзверя
}
```

И не забываем, что пора переходить на [PDO](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_user = ". $email_user ."")); 
    if(isset($row['email_user'])) { $data["error"] = array( "Ошибка" => "Данный E-mail    уже используется" ); }
```